# Yechezkel 26-28 - a reference to America/The West?

Tags: ezekiel--the-book, prophecies

Have there been any Rabbis claim that Yechezkel's prophecy of destruction and lamentations about צֹר/Tyre is also a reference to a modern day country? Clearly the pshat is talking about the ancient city of Tyre, but does that limit it to a single event?

I *believe* I've heard someone claim that it is referring to America (or the west in general), but I am very fuzzy about where that idea came from.

I have done some searching before asking and I have found a couple of christian theories about that, but I believe I heard this in a Jewish context. Sorry for wasting people's time with a gloomy subject if not.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.25.23.5?lang=bi & https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.9.13 thanks @שלום

Comment: Isn't Tyre within the boundaries of EY? Or is it just Sidon?

Comment: @יהושעק happy to find out for you but why would it be relevant?

Comment: According to the [Abarbanel](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.26.14?lang=bi&with=Abarbanel&lang2=en), the new Tyre was on an island just off the Mediterranean coast.

Comment: @RabbiKaii because we don't generally associate places in EY with foreign lands (while we associate plenty of foreign lands with each other).

Comment: @Shmuel indeed, saw this in the Living Torah this yom tov